# Django boolean filter elements in template

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have a Django template where I do queries like this:

```
{% for post in user.post_auctions_set.all %}
```

The point for me now is that I only want to display post elements that don't have the Boolean prime = True.
I came across template tags but never really worked with them.
Can smb. give me a hint on how I could setup a filter like?

views.py

```
def pae(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'App/pae.html', args)
```

models.py

```
class Post_Auctions(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    prime = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Prime", default=False, editable=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the models and view?

Comment: there is, with a `Prefetch` object you can provide a filtered relation to the user object.

Comment: Just added the view and models snippet. Never worked with a Prefetch object i guess. Any hint where to start and how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`if` clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if) form the built-in django template tag set:

```
{% for post in user.post_auctions_set.all %}
    {%  if post.prime %}
    ...
```

Note: this might not be the best solution, but the only I could think of right know, as I am not too familiar with Django right now. At least, what I've read of somewhere somewhen, is to avoid such template logic whenever possible.

Comment: Basically that's a solution yes. But i have to say that's a pain in the A** if you have templates longer than 300 lines as everything gets wrapped up in endless if/else/for etc. statements. But for the moment this seems to be the most effective way. Merci